# How last-child/first-child exactly work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have question how work **first-child** and **last-child** with elements and classes?

Look on my [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9t6/)

And for it I have some question:

1. Why this rule not working:

   ```
   p.test1:first-child{
       color: green;
   }
   ```
2. How then change color of first element with class `test1`?
3. Why this rule working if is similar to example 1:

   ```
   p.test1:last-child{
       color: white;
   }
   ```

Comment: You can think of CSS selectors are of the same priority: `.test` and `:first-child` are two separated, same "level" selectors, both apply to `p` "parallely", so `p.test:first-child` means "`p` which is of class `test`, and also is the first child".

Comment: @Passerby thanks. Nice and short answer. But how in my case select first element with `test1` class?

Comment: In your very specific situation, this can work: http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9t6/12/ (for IE>=9). But it has quite some limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   first child element of its parent.
>
> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   last child element of its parent.

References:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:last-child

1- In your example `p.test1` is not a first child element of its parent, so the selector doesn't select any element.

2- .test1:nth-of-type(4) **Update,** replaced 4 instead of 1, not quiet a solution, Ref:http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo

3- Because it is the last child element of its parent.

Note: the parent here in your example is the `body` tag.

Example in question for future reference:

```
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p class="test1">test</p>
<p class="test1">test</p>
<p class="test1">test</p>
<p class="test1">test</p>
```

Comment: All fine but `.test1:nth-of-type(1)` not working. Working only when I write `.test1:nth-of-type(4)` where 4th element is first with class `test1`... It's weird.

Comment: `.test1:nth-of-type(1)` does not do what you think it does. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107 for an explanation.

Comment: @WooCaSh seems that is the way for now.

Comment: Thank you guys for explain. @BoltClock you should add answer with this link from your comment or can I mark Arbel answer as good?

Answer (score 1):

The first-child/last-child is in relation to the parent element. In your example there is no p.test-element that is the first child of its parent element (The JsFiddle container). Instead the first-child is a plain p-element. If you set the .test-class on the first p-element it turns green.